# How to prevent CSS animation pause, when browser tab suspend

Tags: css, animation

**I have moving line animation, powered by CSS:**

```
.line {
    transition: all 30s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: translate3d(-1000px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

The line is moving 30 seconds to -1000px on X axis.

**The problem:**
When I switch browser tabs to the other websites, animation on the tab with this animation could set on pause, but when I return back to the tab with this animation, animation resumed.

**The behavior I need:**
I need to make animation move constantly without pausing, when user switch the browser tabs.

Comment: _“I need to make animation move constantly without pausing”_ - you can not do that, and neither _should_ you be able to do that, of course. You will need to use JavaScript to _calculate_ what step/percentage your animation should be at, when the user returns to the tab, and then modify the current animation state accordingly.

Comment: the guide here https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/web-animation-performance-fundamentals/, but you must use js

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, then you need to continue the animation after the user has left the current tab of the browser. The `visibilitychange` event will help with this. I have made the usual example code below, but you need to customize this code for your task.

I also specified `line.style.animationPlayState = 'running'` - it is in this place of the condition that the logic of the animation continues.

```
let line = document.querySelector('.line');

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  if (document.visibilityState == 'hidden') {
        line.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
  } else {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is possible with just CSS. For optimization purposes inactive browser tabs or windows are not redrawn. You could however use JavaScript to count how many frames have passed using real time and [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) to skip to the correct frame.